# Split a string then put each word into different group by the length

Tags: php

So I am trying to tokenizes the entire string based on the space and then put those tokens into different groups based on length of those tokens. I got how to split a string by space but I am stuck on put them into different group based on the length. For example, I have a string

> Hello world, this is a test

So after split that string by space, I want to check the length of each token and then put them into different group like

> Group 1: a
>
> Group 2: is
>
> Group 3: test, this
>
> Group 4: hello, world

This is my code so far:

```
$strLength = count($string);
$stringSpl = explode(" ", $string);

    if ($strLength <=  2) { //Here I try to check if the length is less than or equal 2 then place it into group 1
        echo "Group 1: ";

        foreach ($stringSpl as $key) {
            echo $key . "<br/>";
        }
    }
```

Any help would be great! Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to split the string by spaces first and then by asc order of length of the splitted words?

Comment: @Plum yes, that's what I want

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`str_word_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) function along with simple [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) like as

```
$str = "Hello world, this is a test";
$str_arr = str_word_count($str,1);
$result = array();
foreach($str_arr as $v){
    $result["Group ".strlen($v)][] = $v;
}
print_r($result);
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://3v4l.org/7hmLm)

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, instead of trying to figure out the count, use the actual count of letters in each string/word, using [`strlen()`](http://php.net/strlen):

```
$words = explode(" ", $s);
$a = array();
foreach($words as $word){
    $a["Group " . strlen($word)][] = $word;
}

print_r(array_reverse($a));
```

[**Example/Demo**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#8eKByucwI)

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Above answers are great enough, but this is easy

```
<?
    $string = "Hello world, this is a test";
    $strings = array();
    $stringSpl = explode(" ", $string);

    foreach ($stringSpl as $key) {
        $strings[strlen($key)][] = $key;
    }

    $idx = 1;
    foreach ($strings as $array) {
        echo "group ".($idx++).": ";
        foreach ($array as $key) {
            echo $key." ";
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You are right, your answer is easier to look. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$str = "Hello world, this is a test";
$str_arr = str_word_count($str,1);
$result = array();
$i=1;


foreach($str_arr as $v){
$result["Group ".strlen($v)][] = $v;

}
$n=count($result);
echo "<br/>";
$result_array=array_reverse($result);
foreach($result_array as $key=>$value)
{$gorup_value="";

echo $key.' ' ;
$count=count($value);
$i=1;
foreach($value as $key1=>$value1)
{
        $gorup_value .= $value1.',' ;
}
echo    rtrim( $gorup_value , ',');
echo "<br/>";
}
```

Now Edited then Answer Use this

Comment: Thank you so much! How can I trim the very last comma at the end? like `1,2,3,` become `1,2,3`

Comment: I tried this but didn't work `foreach($value as $key1=>$value1) {
    echo rtrim($value1, ',');
    if($i!=$count) {
        echo ", ";
    }
}` any idea?

Comment: no need to use  `rtrim($value1, ',') ` .its working fine with `echo $value`  the above code working fine

Comment: Yes, it works fine, but it prints like `Group 4: this, test,` and `Group 5: Hello, world,` So I just try to trim the last comma right there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104009/discussion-between-bbkay-and-vadivel-s).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!